# Make sync a void method that rises an event, returning event args

Tags: c#, events

Good morning.
Take this simple scenario: I've got a `NetClient` that connects itself to a remote server, using a void method `Connect()`; when done, NetClient rises `Connected` event.

I need to wrap this `NetClient` to another caller that cannot manage async logic like this: this caller wants a sync `Connect()` method that return true if ok (for simplicity don't think about connection errors for now).

The code look like this:

```
    public class Client
    {
        NetClient m_NetClient = new NetClient();

        public void Connect(string ip, int port)
        {
            m_NetClient = new NetClient();
            m_NetClient.Connected += _NetClient_Connected;
            m_NetClient.Connect(ip, port);
        }

        private void _NetClient_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

What can I do to make this logic sync? I need to rise a new thread in event handler than use something like Monitor class?
Can someone give me his opionin/code for achieve this target?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should do the trick.

```
public class Client
        {
            NetClient m_NetClient = new NetClient();
            AutoResetEvent _lock = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            bool result;

            public bool Connect(string ip, int port)
            {
                m_NetClient = new NetClient();
                m_NetClient.Connected += _NetClient_Connected;
                m_NetClient.Connect(ip, port);
                _lock.WaitOne();//wait for thread to finish
                return result;
            }

            private void _NetClient_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //...
                result = e.Result;
                _lock.Set(); //inform waiters
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; I tried using Monitor.Wait e Monitor.Pulse, creting new thread on Connect(), and it seems work.
I will try your solution too, thanks! Nando

Answer (score 1):

OK You need to:

1. Define `AutoResetEvent` as a private member
2. Initialise it in `Connect`
3. After `m_NetClient.Connect(ip, port);` call `WaitOne()`
4. In the `_NetClient_Connected` call `Set()`

## NOTE

What you need to be careful is to not lock your code forever, so you have to handle exceptions and call `Set()` in those cases as well. **Alternatively**, call `WaitOne` with a timeout so that lock is released after some timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, you're right: deadlocks are always behind the corner :)